# Can I use my Android phone as a USB speaker?

Tags: usb, audio, speaker

I have a Lenovo S850 (non-rooted so far, although I've read some guides and may try it when I find the time). Is there a way to use it as a USB speaker for my PC at work, which doesn't have any speakers. I don't have a wireless network there so that is not an option.

I just want to convert my phone to a speaker with as little work as possible, i. e. plug in USB cable, turn on an app and possibly install something on my PC. Is that possible?

**Edit:** This could be relevant: http://www.phonearena.com/news/Android-5.0-Lollipop-supports-USB-DAC-audio-devices-we-go-ears-on_id66399
Also there are lots of USB speakers out there. So with my limited knowledge I guess something like this could be done with only the help of an app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if a USB option is possible but someone please correct me if I'm wrong! This uses the headphone jack so it isn't USB but it is still a wired connection. The following **should** work but may be a bit flaky. Plug a headset jack adapter to split the microphone and audio input into the headphone jack of your phone. Then wire a standard audio cable into the microphone jack of your phone from the audio output of your computer. Last, download [an application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.bitplane.android.microphone) that routes the microphone input to the speaker and turn that on. When you now play audio on your computer, it should be sounded from your phone.

Comment: Actually that's not a bad idea. There were some negative reviews on that app though. Also I still need the usb cable to charge the phone. Not a big problem, but the ideal situation is only the usb cable :)

Comment: OK. I'm not sure if a USB solution is possible but it may be. The negative reviews seem to be down to hardware problems but you could try a different app to do the same thing (of which there are many).

Answer (score 3):

Even though I marked this as answered I feel I need to add that I've managed to do exactly what I wanted with SoundWire and the default internet sharing on my phone as follows:

1. Install and configure SoundWire on PC and phone.
2. Share phone's internet connection via USB.
3. Assuming you already had internet on your PC, you now have 2 network adapters. You need to make sure you are using your old adapter for internet access. As far as I could find to do this you need to change the metric of your default adapter to 1 so that it is the preferred adapter by Windows (Windows 7 in my case).
4. You can check the server IP by typing ipconfig in the command prompt.
5. Connect from the SoundWire app on your phone. You get a message that WiFi is disabled, but it still works fine.

Comment: Ah yes. This is probably a better solution. Very clever!

Comment: Soundwire makes you enable wifi on the phone but actually seems to transfer the data by usb cable. Even if the wifi on the PC is disabled I am still able to get the sound playing on my phone so long as the USB cable is connected. But it won't work if wifi is not enabled on the phone even though it is not transferring data by wireless. It seems suspicious as if the developers really made it as spyware.